# Recursively search word between two files and output match lines as a new file

Tags: bash, join

On slak service, I tried to search users who is joining which channles.
So, I exported following files using by slack api.

1st file is UserID and joined channel (ID_Channel.txt)

```
AAAAAAAAA slack_channel_A
EEEEEEEEE slack_channel_A
JJJJJJJJJ slack_channel_A
CCCCCCCCC slack_channel_B
EEEEEEEEE slack_channel_B
JJJJJJJJJ slack_channel_B
AAAAAAAAA slack_channel_C
CCCCCCCCC slack_channel_C
EEEEEEEEE slack_channel_C
︙
︙
```

2nd file is UserID and e-mail (ID_E-Mail.txt)

```
AAAAAAAAA user1@stackoverflow.com
BBBBBBBBB user2@stackoverflow.com
CCCCCCCCC user3@stackoverflow.com
DDDDDDDDD user4@stackoverflow.com
EEEEEEEEE user5@stackoverflow.com
FFFFFFFFF user6@stackoverflow.com
GGGGGGGGG user7@stackoverflow.com
HHHHHHHHH user8@stackoverflow.com
IIIIIIIII user9@stackoverflow.com
JJJJJJJJJ user10@stackoverflow.com
︙
︙
```

my desired out put is channel & ID & e-mail (sorted by channel) as follows

```
slack_channel_A AAAAAAAAA user1@stackoverflow.com
slack_channel_A EEEEEEEEE user5@stackoverflow.com
slack_channel_A JJJJJJJJJ user10@stackoverflow.com
slack_channel_B CCCCCCCCC user2@stackoverflow.com
slack_channel_B EEEEEEEEE user5@stackoverflow.com
slack_channel_B JJJJJJJJJ user10@stackoverflow.com
slack_channel_C AAAAAAAAA user1@stackoverflow.com
slack_channel_C CCCCCCCCC user3@stackoverflow.com
slack_channel_C EEEEEEEEE user5@stackoverflow.com
︙
︙
```

As you know, users are joining several channels, so I could not use join command. Because, join command does not have recursive option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can** use join. E.g:

```
$ join -j 1 -o 1.2,0,2.2  <(sort id_channel.txt) <(sort id_e-mail.txt) | sort
slack_channel_A AAAAAAAAA user1@stackoverflow.com
slack_channel_A EEEEEEEEE user5@stackoverflow.com
slack_channel_A JJJJJJJJJ user10@stackoverflow.com
slack_channel_B CCCCCCCCC user3@stackoverflow.com
slack_channel_B EEEEEEEEE user5@stackoverflow.com
slack_channel_B JJJJJJJJJ user10@stackoverflow.com
slack_channel_C AAAAAAAAA user1@stackoverflow.com
slack_channel_C CCCCCCCCC user3@stackoverflow.com
slack_channel_C EEEEEEEEE user5@stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response!
Yes, that's my desired output. Thanks a lot!